# What does "the continent" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, swimming-in-the-dark, tomasz-jedrowski

I would like to know what "the continent" means in the following sentences:

> I had known him almost all my life, Beniek. He lived around the corner from us, in our neighbourhood in Wrocław, composed of rounded streets and three-storey apartment buildings that from the air formed a giant eagle, the symbol of our nation. There were hedges and wide courtyards with a little garden for each flat, and cool, damp cellars and dusty attics. It hadn’t even been twenty years since any of our families had come to live there. Our postboxes still said ‘*Briefe*’ in German. Everyone – the people who’d lived here before and the people who replaced them – had been forced to leave their home. From one day to the next, **the continent**’s borders had shifted, redrawn like the chalk lines of the hopscotch we played on the pavement. At the end of the war, the east of Germany became Poland and the east of Poland became the Soviet Union. Granny’s family were forced to leave their land near Lwów. The Soviets took their house and hauled them on the same cattle trains that had brought the Jews to the camps a year or two earlier. They ended up in Wrocław, a city inhabited by the Germans for hundreds of years, in a flat only just deserted by some family we’d never know, their dishes still in the sink, their breadcrumbs on the table. This is where I grew up.

- [Tomasz Jedrowski, *Swimming in the Dark*, Chapter 1](https://www.booker6.com/book/202006/842.html)

In this novel which is set in the 1980's in Poland under the socialist regime, where homosexuality was socially unacceptable, the protagonist Ludwik (a university graduate) left Poland in 1981 to live in the United States of America. And he remembers what it was like back then in Poland, where he used to hang out with his friends including his first love Beniek in his hometown of Wrocław when he was nine years old.

In this part, I wonder whether "the continent" here means the European Continent or simply a continent, a piece of land as opposed to oceans. I am confused because it is not capitalized, but seems to indicate the European continent because the narrator is talking about Germany, Poland, the Soviet Union, all of which are European countries.

I would very much appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The continent" in this context means Europe. As the narrator says, the borders of Poland shifted greatly during and after the Second World War. Wrocław used to be German territory, with the name Breslau, for hundreds of years; Lwów used to be part of Poland. But as a result of World War II, Lwów became the Soviet town of Lviv, and Breslau became the Polish town of Wrocław. "The continent's borders had shifted" refers to this redrawing of boundaries between territories.

Interestingly, Lviv is now a part of Ukraine, as borders were again redrawn all over Eastern Europe and the USSR after the fall of the Soviet empire.

Answer (score 2):

The term "the continent" does not need to be capitalised in order to refer to a specific continent. I've rarely seen Europe referred to as "the Continent" with a capital C, except in contexts where the main part of Europe is being distinguished from other parts (e.g. "Britain and the Continent"), and not always then. The word "the" is already enough to indicate that a specific continent is being referred to, and in context it's clearly Europe.

verbose's answer explains what changes in the borders are being referred to; I just wanted to address your confusion about capitalisation.